# How can you add iOS buttons and features to a Table View based app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

So basically I have made a storyboard based app which consists of table views and text. It is designed to help new programmers like a handbook. You have a table view which allows you to choose a language, a table view which allows you to choose a section (eg initialisation) a table view to choose a subject (e.g. integer) then a text view of how to go about this.

When it was reviewed, they said

> Did not include iOS features. For example, your app was just largely
>   text table views. It would be appropriate to use native iOS buttons
>   and iOS features other than just web views, Push Notifications, or
>   sharing.

I feel like adding these things would degrade from the simplicity and educational purpose of the app. Also, I feel it might be more difficult to navigate if its all iOS button based. Also it might be more difficult to add things later.

So how would you go about adding these things to a table based app so that it can pass the review? I just don't know what they want me to add/change. I have just added a title page with a background image and iOS buttons that direct to the main section a small section and the contact us page. What else can I do?

Comment: I don't think they want you to replace all the tableViews with button based navigation. I believe you can provide some more features like, quick find of a particular item. Let users mark some items as favourite. Share their favourite items to facebook or twitter. One random tip of the day like these features, which will keep users interested in the app.

Answer (score 0):

> how would you go about adding these things to a table based app

I'd start by trying to forget about what I'd already done (since that was rejected) and ask myself: how can I design this using the tools available so that the user can quickly get to the information they need?

UIPickerView comes to mind. Instead of going through three screens just to say what you want, a picker with three sections would let you select all three parameters at once.

It'd be nice if you could provide access to the information in the app several ways. What if I want to browse through all the topics? Do I have to choose one section at a to,e, or can I just start reading? A search feature would be nice, so I can find stuff even when I don't know what section it's in. A tab bar and search field would be useful for these.

Perhaps the most important thing is that however it's designed, your app should look *polished*. It should look like you spent time making it useful and beautiful. Give it some personality.